# How to disable hints on haskell-language-server

Tags: haskell

haskell-language-server is giving me some hints on how to reduce code length, but while I'm learning I would like to disable this hints temporary so I can work on examples from books without the annoying hints polluting the editor. I still want error report, just disable the hints

Here is an example

[image]

Comment: Vim has nothing to do with this as it doesn't natively support LSP. These features are usually handled by either the LSP client or the LSP server. Read their doc, use their issue trackers.

Comment: That's why I mentioned haskell-language-server first, vim was a detail, but I removed from the question anyway. I searched in the haskell-language-server github page but couldn't find anything.

Comment: There's an open issue on adding code actions for ignoring hints here: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/600

But you can still do it manually as the answer below explains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: @JonPurdy mentioned (you should read the great comment bellow) that **Hlint** now supports plain comments like this too:

```hs
{- HLINT ignore "Use <$>" -}
```

unlike `ANN` there is no compile-time or embedding cost attached to this version and it can be placed anywhere - so it's probably the way to go if you need a comment-based solution.

---

you can disable **Hlint** warnings with either a comment in your file or using a hlint-config file (you can find more on both issues in the [hlint manual](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint-1.7/src/hlint.htm)

in this case here the line

```hs
{-# ANN module ("hlint: ignore Use <$>") #-}
```

**after** the `import` section in your file should disable the warning for the *module* (note that it needs to be after the imports - you'll get an parser error otherwise).

---

#### how to use a file

normaly you can create / add those to a `.hlint.yaml` like bellow but as of the comment from @Hjulle this will probably not work.

---

- start by doing `hlint . --default > .hlint.yaml` from your console - you should get the file
- find the section `# Ignore some buildint hints` - you see an example
- add the `- ignore: { name: Use <$> }` option

with this a `hlint src` no longer will show the warning

For VS.Code / LSP it does sadly not work (yet I hope)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! The hints are good but they are annoying when I'm following a tutorial or something. I searched on haskell-language-server documentation and can' t find anything now I understand why, I was looking at wrong place

Comment: HLint now supports using a plain comment `{- HLINT ignore "Use <$>" -}` instead of an `ANN` pragma. `ANN` embeds a value in the compiled module using the same mechanisms as Template Haskell, so it has restrictions on where it can appear, and can lengthen compile times, while a comment can appear anywhere and is just parsed by HLint without affecting compilation. If you have `OverloadedStrings` enabled, `ANN` also requires a type annotation `("…" :: String)` to specify the type of the string literal.

Comment: Thanks - I'll add your comment if you don't mind